# What is the best approach to managing multiple audiences for a pharmaceutical product?

Tags: user-behavior, best-practice, user-journey, audience

I have been looking at the various methods to split the audience and none seem to be ideal.

- interstitial window asking the user to choose patient or Healthcare professional (HCP)
- patient focussed site with a link to a separate HCP site
- keep all content on one site with any audience specific material/activities under a section title For the HCP

This is a new product in the reduction of prominent ears. The site will launch relying on natural search for the patient and the same plus sales people for the HCP. The third group is media.

The patient and the HCP have two different end points to determine a successful visit. The patient to request an appt and the HCP to contact the pharma company to buy the product.

I'd be interested in hearing peoples views on the options and any alternatives that should be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Universities used to have rather clunky links "for students", "for staff" and the like. Now they mostly have sections of the site that fulfil the goals of the different groups. There will obviously be applications which both students and staff will need to log into (the accommodation system, student records etc) but with different levels of access; while some info will be of interest to both groups (university news, etc).

In your situation, I would consider what the requirements & goals are for each group of users:

**Health care professionals**:

- see latest research on prominent ears
- access patient records (?)
- edit the details of their service/practice/consultancy (?)
- sign up for newsletter (?)
- contribute expert articles

**Patients**:

- see news articles on research breakthroughs
- find out what options are available to people with prominent ear syndrome
- understand the costs/benefits/risk of surgery or other interventions
- register for services (?)
- join advocacy group (?)
- sign up for newsletter (?)

Much of the information on the site may well be of interest to both patients and HCPs, so you need to organise it by topic - and then if they log into an application, or sign up for a newsletter, that would be the time to get them to tick a box (I am a patient, or I am a HCP) which will set their preference for the type of content they will receive.

***Benefits of this approach***

- you won't need to develop and maintain two sites
- content will be available to both groups (e.g.  you might have a page with direct links to & summaries of research articles, AND a news page which has links through to the actual journal article - patients may well want to see the research article anyway)
- content will be logically organised by the way it fulfils the needs of the users.